# Change Android Style/Theme smoething like BBM app

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

please dont vote down , if my question isnt clearly. im just newbie

how to make my app style/theme like BBM app

please see this image
[image: topbar]

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.asiabattle.asiabattle" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use  `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`

then go to main activity

in oncreate metod write
{

```
getactionbar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1F2230")));
```

}
u can change color code as u wish.